# Error "Unexpected error" of type "undefined" returned when trying to make a video call

Tags: vline

I'm working on an app using vLine, and trying to establish a video call with a remote user. I get an error. From the Error instance of this error, the "type" is "undefined", the "message" is "Unexpected error".

Very hard to figure out where a problem is with error messages like this. How is one supposed to debug one's code with this kind of information?

Here's my code:

```
    call : function(remoteUserID, videoElementID) 
    { 
        RSSession.getPerson(remoteUserID).
            done(function(person) 
            { 
                setVideoElement(videoElementID);
                var AMedia = person.startMedia();
                Calls.push(new MyCall(AMedia)); 
                person.release(); 
            }).
            fail(function(error)
            {
                alert("Application Error: (call) " + error.message + ",type=" + error.type);
            }); 
    },
```

A few notes:

1. This code is adapted from example code in the Shell Example and the
   sample code in the API descriptions.
2. The `remoteUserID` exists and is defined. Likewise, `videoElementID` is an existing HTML element.
   `setVideoElement` just sets a variable; it works up to here.
3. It looks like it dies trying to do `person.startMedia()'.
4. And `person` is a legitimate person that is returned - of the form `/serviceid/userid` (I checked all these during my debugging).
5. `RSSession` also exists and is created during the client `create` and `login` steps, all of which work OK.
6. Again, in the `fail`, the error "type" is "undefined", the "message" is "Unexpected error".

So, any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: Regarding point 4, did you mean `serviceId:userId`? It should have a colon separator, not slashes.

Comment: Yes, my mistake - it was actually `/user/serviceID:userID`

Comment: Can you try adding console.log() messages before and after every line in the done() closure (including after person.release()) so we can verify exactly where it's failing?

Comment: Also, if you can print out the value of `remoteUserID`, that would be helpful. We've seen some error logs on our servers that look like you might be passing URLs in as the `remoteUserID`.

Comment: Tom, I already did add the console.log() in all the lines; that's how i was able to ascertain what was working and where it failed. 

It never gets to person.release, failing (it seems) at the person.StartMedia() step (i.e, nothing is displayed after this step is reached, and the fail closure is invoked). 

The remoteUserID is a test user's Facebook ID (we use Facebook as a login mechanism, and use the user's Facebook ID as the user id in vLine). Again, i have verified that and it's definitely a known user's Facebook Id, and certainly not a URL. Had i seen that, I would have fixed it.

Comment: So, for instance, for `person`, I see `/user/realsheek:1037832395`, and the `remoteUserID` value is 1037832395.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33221/discussion-between-tom-vline-and-lew)